# Custom width and height on fancybox image

Tags: jquery, fancybox, height, width

I wonder if it is posible to set a custom width and height on fancybox images?

As a standard, the width and height of the fancybox changes in relative to the width and height of the images, but i want to be 800 width and 600 height, at all images.

I want to create something familiar to the image-box on facebook, where you see the image at the left, and description and comments at the right.

Could be great if someone could help me with this... :)

- TheYaXxE

Answer (score 20):

A simpler way is to change the size of both, the fancybox opened image AND the fancybox parent container using the `beforeShow` callback like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false, // avoids scaling the image to fit in the viewport
    beforeShow: function () {
        // set size to (fancybox) img
        $(".fancybox-image").css({
            "width": 800,
            "height": 600
        });
        // set size for parent container
        this.width = 800;
        this.height = 600;
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fgqNX/)**

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.x+

---

**EDIT** (April 2014) :

With the current version of fancybox (v2.1.5 as today), it's not necessary to apply css rules to the `.fancybox-image` selector since images are now set to be responsive (`max-width: 100%;`). `this.width` and `this.height` alone will do the trick

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false,
    beforeShow: function () {
        this.width = 800;
        this.height = 600;
    }
});
```

See forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YhLLF/)**

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore  in v3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I am using FancyBox V3, for me "beforeShow" did not work rather "beforeLoad" worked.